# struct inside union and union having struct pointer. how to access them?

Tags: c, structure, unions

I'm working on structs and unions.

```
typedef struct _test {

        int te; 

}test;

typedef struct _resp {

        int type;
        union {
                test *testptr;    
        }u;

}resp_t;

resp_t *resp;
```

how to access te using resp?

Comment: Hem, the point with the union is that it has *at least two members* that overlay each other in the memory, yet your union has *one*...

Answer (score 1):

> how to access te using resp?

```
resp->u.testptr->te;
```

Comment: I allocated memory like resp_t *resp = (resp_t *)malloc(sizeof(resp_t)); but when i access te like, resp->u.testptr->te; I get core dump. Am I missing anything?

Comment: You didn't initialize `testptr`. As the `testptr` is not initialized, dereferencing it `->` most probably results in segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to allocate enough space for your `resp_t` strcuture. 
To access the element, just do `resp->u.testprt->te`

Comment: I allocated memory like
resp_t *resp = (resp_t *)malloc(sizeof(resp_t));

but when i access te like, resp->u.testptr->te; I get core dump. Am I missing anything?